# How to reference to the variable as it was in a loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, variables, konvajs

With the following code, I want being logged in the console 1 2 and 3 depending on the rectangle under the pointer. What I get is always the last value, three.

I don't undestand why and how can I solve the problem.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@2.4.2/konva.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
 
<script>
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 100,
    height: 100
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);
 
for (var i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    var rect = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 10,
        y: 30*i,
        width: 50,
        height: 20,
        fill: "red",
        stroke: "black",
        strokeWidth: 4
    });
   
    layer.add(rect);
   
    rect.on("mousemove", function() {
     console.log(i);
    });
}
   
stage.draw();

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your `mousemove` event havppening, `i` is already and always will be `3`

Try to use `let i=0` instead of `var i=0`. with `let` your `i` variable will be in local loop scope so will be related to the `layer`

Code:

```js
 var stage = new Konva.Stage({
     container: 'container',
     width: 100,
     height: 100
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);
 
for (let i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    var rect = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 10,
        y: 30*i,
        width: 50,
        height: 20,
        fill: "red",
        stroke: "black",
        strokeWidth: 4
    });
   
    layer.add(rect);
   
    rect.on("mousemove", function() {
     console.log(i);
    });
}
   
stage.draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@2.4.2/konva.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Another option is to pass `i` into your handler function:

```js
var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 100,
    height: 100
});

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);
 
for (var i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    var rect = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 10,
        y: 30*i,
        width: 50,
        height: 20,
        fill: "red",
        stroke: "black",
        strokeWidth: 4
    });
   
    layer.add(rect);
   
    rect.on("mousemove", (function(i) {
        return function(e) { 
            console.log(i)
        };
    })(i));
}
   
stage.draw();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@2.4.2/konva.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: I'm using old javascript code and I cannot use let

Comment: I updated an answer